Help on a proof using implication
I am trying to prove the following statement:
Let $a,b\in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$
$$
[(\exists n \in \mathbb{N} : a=nb) \wedge (\exists n \in \mathbb{N} : b=na)]\Rightarrow a = b
$$
Here is what I've come up with:
$$
[(\exists n \in \mathbb{N} : a=nb) \wedge (\exists n \in \mathbb{N} : b=na)]\Rightarrow a = b \\ \equiv \\ 
(\forall n \in \mathbb{N} : a\neq nb) \vee (\forall n \in \mathbb{N} : b\neq na) \vee a = b 
$$
if $a=b$ then we are done, if $a\neq b$, then choose $a$ and $b$ such that $a=\frac{b}{n}$, then $(\forall n \in \mathbb{N} : b\neq na)$ is false but $(\forall n \in \mathbb{N} : a\neq nb)$ is true and thus the proposition is always true.
Does this seem to be correct? The thing that is nagging me in my proof is that when we say "Let $a,b\in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$" do we mean litteraly for any $a,b$ in the sense that no matter which $a$ or $b$ it works, or can we choose the a and b like I did as a function of each other?

$a,b$ are given. For specific $a,b$ this is easy. You are not free to pick them.

Ah okay, thank you very much

As a hint for this problem: prove it directly and use the total order of $\mathbb{N}$

Malady, how so? i do not see how I can prove it directly, nor how the total order of $\mathbb{N}$ plays into this...

@realreal if $a$ divides $b$ then $a\leq b$, if $b$ divides $a$ then…

You can't "choose" $a$ and $b$  if what you are trying to prove is an assertion about $a$  and $b$. In words: you want to show that for real numbers $a$ and $b$, $a$ is a natural number  multiple of $b$ and $b$ is one of $a$ then $a$ must equal $b$. These proofs are always easier to write and to understand with words rather than formal logical expressions/

It's a bit annoying that this has been closed. For once someone makes a solution-verification post with a concrete question, as proscribed by the tag description, and then it gets closed anyway with a reason that completely ignores the concrete question OP had.

Your doubts are justified.

Let $a,b\in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$ $$ [(\exists n \in \mathbb{N}
> : a=nb) \wedge (\exists n \in \mathbb{N} : b=na)]\Rightarrow a = b $$

means you have to prove

$$\forall a,b\in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}: \Big([(\exists n \in
> \mathbb{N} : a=nb) \wedge (\exists n \in \mathbb{N} :
> b=na)]\Rightarrow a = b \Big)$$


Ah yes, I see, thank you for the clarification
